# Bootstrap javascript wordpress issue data-toggle="collapse"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with a project.

This is the first wordpress blog I do, the idea was the html site [www.humantools.com.mx](http://www.humantools.com.mx) and build a blog for it [www.humantools.com.mx/blog](http://www.humantools.com.mx/blog) I have a weird problem, when loged the class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" in the navbar works well, in the site it works well...

when I log out,  the nav item that normally brings the colapssed menu links to "#"

this is odd, I'm really hitting my head with this, please help, I'm adding the css and the header code, if you need anything else please let me know.

---

**HEADER**

```
<?php
          
  /**
  
  * The Header template for our theme
  
  *
  
  * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
  
  *
  
  * @package WordPress
  
  * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
  
  * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
  
  */
  
  ?>
  
  <!--[if IE 7]>
  
  <html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  
  <![endif]-->
  
  <!--[if IE 8]>
  
  <html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  
  <![endif]-->
  
  <!--[if !(IE 7) & !(IE 8)]><!-->
  
  <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
  
  <!--<![endif]-->
  
  <head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <meta name="description" content="">
  
  <meta name="author" content="">
  
  <link rel="icon" href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/img/favicon.png">
  
  
  
  <title>Human Tools</title>
  
  
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
  
  ================================================== -->
  
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="http://www.humantools.com.mx/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="http://www.humantools.com.mx/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  
  <script src="http://www.humantools.com.mx/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <script>
  
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  
  ga('create', 'UA-56728201-1', 'auto');
  
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  
  </script>
  
  
  
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  
  <link href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- Custo Fonts -->
  
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:200,400,300,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  
  <link href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  
  <![endif]-->
  
  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  
  <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
  
  <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
  
  <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
  
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  
  <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
  
  <![endif]-->
  
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
  
  </head>
  
  <?php echo '<body class="'.join(' ', get_body_class()).'">'.PHP_EOL; ?>
  
  <!-- NAVBAR
  
  ================================================== -->
  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="navbar-header">
  
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
  
      <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
  
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  
    </button>
  
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/"><img src="http://www.humantools.com.mx/img/logo-humantools.png"></a>
  
  </div>
  
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  
      <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/quienessomos.html">Quiénes<br>Somos</a></li>
  
      <li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Soluciones<br>para Empresas <span class="caret"></span></a>
  
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  
          <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/outsourcing.html">Outsourcing <br>de Nómina</a></li>
  
          <li class="divider"></li>
  
          <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/procesamiento.html">Procesamiento <br>de Nómina</a></li>
  
        </ul>
  
      </li>
  
      <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/contacto.html">Info &<br>Contacto</a></li>
  
      <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/faq.html">Preguntas<br>Frecuentes</a></li>
  
      <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/avisodeprivacidad.html">Aviso de<br>Privacidad</a></li>
  
                  <li><a href="http://www.humantools.com.mx/blog">Blog<br><br></a></li>
  
  
  
    </ul>
  
  </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  
  </div>
  
  </nav>
  
  
  
  <!-- CONTENIDO
  
  ================================================== -->
  
  
  
  <div class="container">
  
  <div class="col-lg-9"> <!-- titulo blog -->
```

**CSS**

```
/*
Theme Name:HumanTools.
Theme URI: www.humantools.com.mx
Description: Human Tools blog.
Version: 1.0
Author: Raul Salazar 
Author URI: www.bybrave.com
*/
body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.home {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.interior {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  color: #0876bb;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 15% 0% 9% 0%;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}

.faq-divider {
    color: #adadad;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

NAV STARTS

```
         .navbar {
          min-height: 78px;
}

.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #212121;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 120%;
}

.nav>li {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-left: solid 1px #0876bb;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

li {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color: #212121;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #888;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #FFF;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #0876bb;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

NAV ENDS

```
/* blog */
div .date {
margin: 40% 0px 0px 55%;
font-size: 18px;
}

.blog6 { max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
}
.contenidoblog {
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:1.2em;
}
.tag {
font-size:16px;}
.bluetag {
    color: #0876bb;
font-size:16px;
}

.masblog { font-size:18px; text-transform:capitalize;
margin-bottom:30px;}

.sidebar {margin-top: 10%; }
/*end blog*/
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  height: 440px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  top: 40px;
  left: 5%;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel .item {
  height: 440px;
  background-color: #0876bb;
  background-image: url(img/slide-01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  min-width: 1024px;
  height: 440px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.carousel-control {
    height: 510px;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE QUOTES
-------------------------------------------------- */
.quotes {
   margin-top: -10px;
}

hr {
    color: #adadad;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.quote {
    border: solid 1px #adadad;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 30px 30px;
}

#quote-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 5px;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background-image: url('img/quote-left.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#quote-img2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 29px;
    height: 29px;
    background-image: url('img/quote-right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#quote-img3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 36px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url('img/quote-corner.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE INTERIORS
-------------------------------------------------- */

.blue {
    color: #0876bb;
}

.grey {
    color: #888888;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.subheading {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

.contenido {
    text-align: justify;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

ul li.bullet-01 {
    background-image: url(img/bullet-01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 22px; 
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul li.bullet-02 {
    background-image: url(img/bullet-02.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px 22px; 
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul li.bullet-a {
    background-image: url(img/bullet-a.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 14px; 
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul li.bullet-b {
    background-image: url(img/bullet-b.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 14px; 
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}

ul li.bullet-c {
    background-image: url(img/bullet-c.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 14px; 
    padding: 15px 0 15px 40px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.img-responsive {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE FORM
-------------------------------------------------- */

.form-control {
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #0876bb;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin-right: -15px;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE FOOTER
-------------------------------------------------- */

.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -31;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.f1 {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 30px 0 20px 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: .5px
}

.f1 a {
    color: #fff;
} 

.f1 em {
    color: #0876bb;
}

.text-mutted {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #888;
        padding: 30px 0 20px 0px;
}


@media (max-width: 990px) {
    #quote-img3 {
        bottom: -23px;
    }

    .f1 {
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    width: 60%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {

    .copyright {
        margin-top: 130px;
    }

    .f1 {
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
}

function mbe_wp_head(){
    echo '<style>'.PHP_EOL;
    echo 'body{ padding-top: 70px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using custom CSS class name.
    echo 'body.body-logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    // Using WordPress default CSS class name.
    echo 'body.logged-in .navbar-fixed-top{ top: 28px !important; }'.PHP_EOL;
    echo '</style>'.PHP_EOL;
} 

#respond { 
background: #ffffff;
padding:10px;
margin-top:-15%;
}

/* Highlight active form field */

#respond input[type=text], textarea {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 30px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
 
 
#respond input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}

#author { 
font-family: Lobster, "Lobster 1.4", "Droid Sans", Arial;
font-size: 16px;
color:#1d1d1d; 
letter-spacing:.1em;
} 

#url  { 
color: #21759b;
font-family: "Luicida Console", "Courier New", "Courier", monospace; 
} 

#submit {
font-family: Arial;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
border:0px;
border-top: 2px solid #0992e6;
background: #0773b5;
} 

#submit:hover {
  background: #0869a4;
    border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0992e6;
text-shadow: 0px;
color:#cecece;
}

#commentform > p.logged-in-as {margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

Answer (score 4):

These 3 files are returning a [404](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). You can see these buy opening up the [JavaScript console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) in your browser.

> http://www.humantools.com.mx/prueba/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js 
>   http://www.humantools.com.mx/prueba/assets/js/docs.min.js 
>   http://www.humantools.com.mx/prueba/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js

The most important file is **bootstrap.min.js** which needs to be included. You should include bootstrap in your project like this - make sure that you have it in the directory you say you have: https://github.com/pjhampton/BigBooty/blob/master/lib/framework/enqueue.php

Comment: in my header i have then in a different directory http://www.humantools.com.mx/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js :/

and I have them in that directory, anyway I added the directory and loaded a copy of the files there and it got fixed, but would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: You would really want to locate the bootstrap.min.js file at the bottom of the DOM. It wasn't working first of all because it could not read the files.

Comment: oddly enough I got it to work... I basically went through an extensive troubleshooting. 

thanks for the comment, it did helped a lot :)